# Search via GET: adding/removing parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, search, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a bunch of links and toggle buttons for filtering. I want to be able to add/remove search arguments from a URL depending on the state of toggle buttons and whether or not a parameter has already been added into the URL. That is, if parameter is already in a URL, it should either be removed or changed to its opposite value when I click a link/toggle button assosicated with that parameter. Without javascript. That is, I should generate an appropriate link for each link/button on backend. The URL might look something like:

```
     /search?q=aaa&filter1=123
     /search?q=aaa&filter1=123&filter2=555&filter3=aaaaaaaa
```

When pressing the link "filter2", it should become:

```
    /search?q=aaa&filter1=123&filter3=aaaaaaaa
```

I can, of course,  do that by analyzing a URL manually on backend. But I wonder, isn't there an easier and more general way? I think params.merge(...) and params.slice(...) might be used, but how? If at all.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show [what you have tried so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include a [mcve] of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Comment: @TobySpeight, no.

Comment: you can use ERB to craft the links, or use forms, or use Javascript. Showing your attempt encourages answerers because it means they don't have to start from scratch; you'll probably get a higher-quality answer that way.